# How to debug problems in [Authorize] attribute

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-active-directory

#### The problem

That's everything in the title, really. I have an `[Authorize]` attribute that's always returning 401 and I don't know why. How can I step through the logic behind it?

#### A little more detail

I'm trying to use Azure AD authorization via JWT tokens. I've done this successfully with other projects, so I'm sure the problem is some minor configuration issue, but as far as I can tell, the only interaction I get to have with `[Authorize]` is in `Startup.cs`, where I have this:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            SaveSigninToken = true,
        },
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
    });
```

But that bit only runs when the application starts. Otherwise, `[Authorize]` is kind of a black box to me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are using `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`. You will always get 401 unless you provide a `valid bearer token` as an `authorization header` in your request. Bearer Token Authentication is used for WebAPIs. There will be no redirect or whatsoever when you use `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication`. And if you are really trying WebAPI, then you really get the wrong bearer token.

Comment: As I mentioned, this snippet is taken from a working project, where the full auth chain works fine. My issue is that I'm trying to re-use the code in a new project. At some point I probably put in the wrong App ID or some other minor detail. The whole issue here is that I'm not sure how to debug `[Authorize]` to find my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

try put breakpoint in OnAuthenticationFailed method of JwtBearerEvents class, there you can read exception message and then set your config accordingly

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["OIDC:Authority"];
                options.Audience =  Configuration["OIDC:Audience"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new 
                TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["OIDC:Issuer"]                        
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {                        
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctx => 
                     {
                         var putBreakpointHere = true;
                         var exceptionMessage = ctx.Exception;
                     },
                };
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to debug my jwt token by

injecting HttpAccessor in Startup ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

using it in Controller

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyController(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
```

and getting the data from headers

```
var jwt = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Fiddler traces for debugging. You can take a look at the ASP.NET sample here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect